# Бинарное чтение 7z архива

Tags: 7z, c++

Доброго времени суток, нужна небольшая помощь. Есть архив 7z, как из него можно достать список файлов. Т.е. нужно найти позицию байта в котором лежит кол-во файлов и прочитать через структуру.

```
struct FileInfo
{
    список параметров по файлам.
};

fread(&fileinfo, sizeof(fileinfo), 1, file);
```

Вот проблема в том, что не знаю ни под каким байтом начинается список файлов. и размер структуры :(

Спасибо.

Comment: Может быть посмотреть в сторону 7z api?
http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html

Возможоно там уже есть методы для получения информации по архиву вместо реверс-инжениригна и чтения байтов напрямую.

Comment: к сожалению, юзать доп. библиотеки нельзя :(

Comment: Ну так путём чтения исходных кодов SDK поймёте и структуру файла.